# A problem with special character in Vim script

Tags: vimscript, neovim, abbreviations

I'm trying to build a `diacritic` plugin which It's just a list of commands like

```
ia <leader>'e é " this one is source just fine
ia <leader>ae æ " This one causes error
```

But I'm seeing an error `E474` when the file gets sourced.

I can't find a way to debug it, any help with this?

Comment: try the `:scriptencoding` command

Comment: I my tests the problem is not related to the æ character but to the `<leader>ae` sequence. If you try `ia ae æ` I believe it will work. I don't what are the lhs that are refused by `ia`.

Comment: @Ekiim, is the answer addressing your question or do you have some aspect that are not addressed. If the proposed solution address your question I would propose you to accept it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: It did help a lot, Thanks @VivianDeSmedt

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every character sequences are acceptable for abbreviation (see: `:h abbreviation`).

To determine if a sequence is supported the last character is important.

If the last character is a non-keyword character (usually a letter, a number or an underscore) the sequence is supported (`non-id` sequence). Example are: `#foo#`, `foo#`, `bar##`

If the last character is a keyword character there are two types of sequence supported:

1. The part before is only made of keyword characters (`full-id` sequence). Example are: `foo`, `bar`
2. The part before is only made of non-keyword characters (`end-id` sequence). Example are: `#a`, `#.#b`

If the last character is a keyword you can't mix keyword and non-keyword on the first part. Example are: `\ae`

Remark: The definition of what is a keyword character can be configured using the `iskeyword` option (more information with `:h 'iskeyword'`)

I could recommend you to either use the suffix approach:

```
ia e'\ é
ia ae\ æ
```

Or use the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1680834/329318) that propose to check the character before the abbreviation and delete it before inserting the abbreviation.